# How to log results as and when available without losing it during a crash?

Tags: python, logging

I have a set of Python test scripts which executes the case and then logs the result in a log file - at the end of the test case every time. The problem with this approach is if my program crashes unexpectedly, the log file won't be generated. This is a sample of my test scripts

```
id = "mytest"
def scr1(control, log):
    res = False
    try:
        log.opencase(id)

        log_format = "result 1 {:s}; result 2 {:s};"
        #sample step 1
        log.log_output("step 1 output")
        #calculate var1, var2

        #sample step 2
        log.log_output("step 2 output")
        #calculate var3, var4

        log_format = "Output 1 = {:s}; Output 2 = {:s};"

        #Populate the results I need
        result1 = log_format.format (var1, var2)
        result2 = log_format.format(var3,var4)

       log.log_final(result1)
       log.log_final(result2)

       #check if result1 = result2 - if yes, set res = True

    except Exception as ex:
        log.error("Ex"+ex)
        res = False

    finally:
        if res:
            print("PASS")
        else:
            print("FAIL")
            log.log_output("Logging program output here")

        log.close_case(res)
        return res
```

All my scripts are in this format. Is there a way that wihtout changing the scripts I can achieve logging the outputs as soon as it is available, and saving them in the log file rather than losing them if the program crashes?

My logging function sample:

```
LOG_INFO = 'info'
LOG_OUTPUT = 'timestamp'
#Make an XML of type "output"
def log_output(self, txt):
    if self.Echo:
        print(txt)
        elem = et.SubElement(self.testname, LOG_OUTPUT, {LOG_TIMESTAMP: self._get_timestamp()})
        elem.txt = txt
        self.linear_log(LOG_OUTPUT + txt)

def linear_log(self, msg):
    if self.LinearLog:
        lin = open(self.LinearLog, "a")
        lin.write(self._get_timestamp() + msg)
        lin.close()

#Make an XML element
def log_final(self, str):
    if self.Echo:
        print("Final" + text)
    element = et.SubElement(self.testname,self._get_timestamp())
    element.text = str
    self.linear_log(text)
```

When I say crash - I mean - a hardware crash. A hardware failure. These scripts are sending commands to a hardware (a test camera) and the camera performs certain operations. But at times, some modules in the camera might fail as it is a test device. Under such circumstances, I end the script clicking either clicking the red square (end) button on Pycharm as sometimes the script doesn't respond if it doesn't get an expected response from the camera - and I see nothing logged in the log file as it wasn't a graceful exit.

The script runs on a windows machine and stores the log in it. The camera is connected via serial port.

The problem is with logging log.log_final(result1) and log.log_final(result2). If the hardware crashes before reaching this step, ie if the hardware crashes while calculating var3 and var4, it doesn't log log.log_final for result1 and result2 though var1 and var2 are available. Is there a specific logic that I can apply to log the "available data" (here var1 and var2) every time rather that the program waiting for all the data it needs for logging?

Comment: What is `mylogger`? How is it implemented? Does `close_case` actually handle the flushing of output to disk?  Really though, it looks like `result` is not actually assigned inside the `scr1` function you have provided in the question, and the `finally` block will crash instantly on `if result:` (as `result` is not declared) and thus none of the remaining statement (including `close_case`) will execute.

Comment: I had many of the same questions as metatoaster.  Depending on the scope of mylogger, you could wrap the whole thing in a try/except block and close mylogger on error.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster - log is an instance of Logger (Logger.py) which is well implemented and working. I missed out the result assignment previously as this is just a sample code. Thanks for pointing it out, added now.. Close case handles flushing the output.

Comment: In any case, with the code provided in the question we are unable to easily replicate the exact problem you have.  It would be useful if you can investigate this further and provide the minimum code needed to reproduce the exact issue you are seeing.  The code provided does not indicate exactly how the failure to write might occur.  Is there a traceback that is produced by the program that might indicate why what you want to log isn't?  Are you calling native code that caused a segmentation fault?  As I said, there really isn't sufficient detail in here for any of us to help you debug.

Comment: @metatoaster - Much appreciated :) I will get back with more info after a bit more debugging. I was suspecting that I was doing something wrong with the way I do the 'log.log_output' which eventually failed to write in he log file. May be I will have to take a look at 'Logger.py' in detail.

Comment: @metatoaster - A bit more information added to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Clarifying that as a hardware crash was useful, but unfortunately graceful handling of hardware crashes generally falls outside of the control of any userspace processes (i.e. your Python application), as the failure lies within the underlying layer, assuming that the logs are written to the failing device. The other interpretation from what you wrote is that you mentioned Pycharm not responding, this generally indicates a hung process somewhere and thus it never got to the point where the writing of the logs would happen, which may also be the cause of your failure.

Comment: Hi @metatoaster - I have added more details and a bit more of code explaining why logging I need (log_final) doesn't work. It is obvious why it doesn't get logged - as the execution never reaches there. I am looking for alternatives which may help me log available data rather than waiting for all the data to get populated? For eg, the program stops responding when the hardware fails while calculating var3 and var4..

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest solution be moving the logic relating to the calculation and storage of `result1` before starting step 2?

Comment: @metatoaster - Probably yes - but there are some scripts which generates only var1 in step1. var2 is generated down the lane even after generating var 3 and var4 may be. Could you please advice if it would be safe/ideal to do log.log_final(result1) after step1 if var2 is not available? On another thought - I can log them (all vars) individually as and when it is available. But just wondering if there is a better way to handle this as I want to make the logs readable, grouped (w.r.t variables and their comparisons) and modifiable in the future too..

Comment: Sounds like your "log" is more akin to the "output" of the program, as the values generated are interdependent on each other; for actual useful logging done for diagnostic purposes typically this means the values are written out (either stdout or disk) **immediately** after they are generated into a separate raw log that captures the results for each processing steps done by the program.  Alternatively you would just simply initialise the unavailable values to some sentinel value (e.g. `None` or `NotImplemented`) and simply log those instead.